# Duda C#: imprimir elementos List

Tags: c#

Buenas he creado el siguiente List, y añadido varios elementos como muestro a continuación:

```
List<Persona> personas = new List<Persona>();

personas.Add(new Persona("12345678C", "Juan Francisco Cabello"));
personas.Add(new Persona("26810168B", "Jesus Romero Gonzalez"));
personas.Add(new Persona("32167678V", "Guillermo Barcia"));

for (int i = 0; i < personas.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("INTRODUCIDO: " + personas[i].toString());
    sw.WriteLine(personas[i].toString());
    sw.WriteLine();
}
```

El problema es que el console, solo me muestra el último elemento ("Guillermo Barcia").

Ahí dejo la clase Persona

```
class Persona : IComparable<Persona>  
{
     #region Atributos
     private static string dni;
     private static string nombre;
     #endregion
     #region Propiedades
     public string Dni { get => dni; set => dni = value; }
     public string Nombre { get => nombre; set => nombre = value; }
     #endregion
     #region Constructores
     public Persona(string dn, string nom)
     {
          dni = dn;
          nombre = nom;
     }
     public Persona() { }
     #endregion
     #region CompareTo
     public int CompareTo(Persona other)
     {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
     }
     #endregion
     #region ToString
     public string ToString()
     {
           return "Nombre: " + nombre + "\n" +
                  "DNI: " + dni;
     }
     #endregion
}
```

Comment: Por un lado tienes un error tipográfico en `toString`, ya que debe empezar con mayuscula. Por otro, deberías mostrar la definicion de la clase Persona. Y, por ultimo, para mostrar el nombre deberías haber sobreescrito el método `ToString`,es así? Mas allá de eso, el código que muestras es correcto.

Comment: método ToString corregido.

Comment: sigue sin funcionar :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que tienes el un poco complicado de ver para alguien nuevo en la programación.

La cuestión es que has marcado tus variables privadas `dni` y `nombre` como `static`. Esto hace que en todas las instancias de `Persona`, estas variables sean la misma, con lo que al ir asignando los nombres en el constructor de la clase, estás modificando estas variables privadas en todas las instancias previas.

Simplemente, elimina el modificador `static` y debería funcionarte correctamente.

P.D.

Creo que has creado el método `toString` (con minuscula la primera) para imprimir los datos. En realidad, es más correcto sobreescribir el método por defecto `ToString`. Para ello, la definición debe ser `public override string ToString()`. `override` indica que sobreescribes el método.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias compañero, me funciona a la perfección.